# Connect Foot and palm switch to Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, raspberry-pi-os

We made a project using a raspberry pi and 4 arcade buttons (https://thepihut.com/products/massive-arcade-button-with-led-100mm-white) sadly there were not robust enough, it is used inside a playground for entry, and 2 broke in the span of 2 weeks.

We were getting power from these on a simple GPIO PIN 3/4 for example, this kinda worked but i bet it will not work with the more robuust buttons we wanna buy:

https://www.automation24.co.uk/foot-and-palm-switch-eaton-229746-fak-r-kc11-i
or the 5v
https://www.automation24.co.uk/foot-and-palm-switch-siemens-sirius-act-3su1801-2ga00-2aa1
We were thinking of buying 4 of the above one, can anyone helm me out regarding the button receive on a GPIo from this button.

And will this work with the simple raspberry pi wires?

All help is very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `We were getting power from these on a simple GPIO PIN 3/4` ... a switch does not provide power ... a switch is just two wires being touched together ... you could use two coffee spoons as a switch if you wanted